Penalty method for optimization with one limit
The task is to find minimum of function:
$$ \ f(x,y,z) = 3*x^2+y^2+z^2 $$
with following limit:
$$ \    g(x,y,z) = x+y+z=2    $$
using Penalty function method (and Fermat's method for unconditional optimization).
As initial points I choose x = 1, y = 0.5, z = 0.5 (they meet the constraint g(x,y,z))
As I understand, I need to calculate gradient of following expression:
$$ \    F=f(x,y,z) + \alpha*g(x,y,z), $$
where $$ \alpha $$ - is some coefficient (let say = 0.1)
So:
$$ \     ∂F/∂x = (3*x^2+y^2+z^2 + 0.1*(x+y+z-2)^2)' = 6x +0.1*(2(x+y+z))  $$
$$ \     ∂F/∂y = (3*x^2+y^2+z^2 + 0.1*(x+y+z-2)^2)'= 2x +0.1*(2(x+y+z))  $$
$$ \     ∂F/∂z = (3*x^2+y^2+z^2 + 0.1*(x+y+z-2)^2)'= 2x +0.1*(2(x+y+z))  $$
Equal particular derivatives to 0:
$$ \    6x +0.1*(2(x+y+z)) = 0 $$
$$ \    2x +0.1*(2(x+y+z)) = 0 $$
$$ \    2x +0.1*(2(x+y+z)) = 0 $$
Solving this system, I receive:
$$ \    x=0  , z=-y    $$
And all this points does not meet the constraint: x+y+z=2
As I understand, then I need to continue iterations.
But what are the following steps?
And may be I made mistakes in my previous steps, as I don't understand this method clearly?

are you sure that you got the method right? usually, in the penalty decomposition method, you would solve a sequence of unconstrained optimization problems, instead of a constrained problem, something like $F_{\alpha}=f+\alpha g^2$ as $\alpha$ goes to infinity!

I'm not sure, that I got the method right ))  In particular, I confused with result:            x =0,   y = -z

I'm not sure, that I got the method right ))  In particular, I confused with result:            x =0,   y = -z.   Because, when I up coefficient in the following iteration from 0.1 to (let say) 0.9,  i'll receive the same result: x =0,   y = -z.

Use some sources to learn PD more accurately. This is well-established!
